# Help with formatting HDDs and removing partitions that were used in Windows before

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have a desktop computer with only Ubuntu 20.04 installed. I have a few HDDs inside for storage that were used in a windows system before and are showing small windows partitions that I'm not able to remove with the Disks app, there is an error every time I try. Does someone knows how to wipe completely these drives and have them like factory new? I really don't want to see these little partitions anymore. thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: With Gparted, Device menu > New partition table (choose GPT because it's much better than the alternatives) it's a guaranteed way of cleaning everything. Then you can create new partitions. That said, I don't know what exactly you're talking about and I suspect the drives are maybe defective.

Comment: If Windows fast start up is still on, the hibernation flag is set on the NTFS partitions. Then the Linux tools will not work on them to prevent damage to the hibernated systems. You may need to remove the hibernation flag. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 0):

Gparted should be able to do this. It's pre-installed on a live USB but not the normal installation, but you can download it from Ubuntu Software. You should be able to see / resize / delete any partition that isn't currently mounted using Gparted. If you want to delete all partitions except for the one you are using (ie the live Ubuntu partition) then there is no risk ... obviously if there is anything on any of the partitions you might ever want, be very careful about which ones you select to delete.